# caret::bagEarth and reproducibility

Tags: r, r-caret

I've noticed that every time I use `caret::bagEarth`, my answers are a little different. I've tried `set.seed` preceding it, but to no effect. Is there a way I can get the same answer from the function every time it is run?

Here is a very poor model of just random numbers, but it should be reproducible:

```
library(caret)
predictors<-data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*1000, 18, .5), ncol=5))
response<-data.frame(matrix(rbinom(2*1000, 221:382, .5), ncol=1))

set.seed(222)
bag_mods<-bagEarth(x = predictors, response, B = 20, keepX = TRUE)
```

Comment: `set.seed` does seem to help. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I get different summary statistics every time I run this example.

Comment: And how do you obtain them? For instance, `tail(bag_mods$oob)` is always the same. Perhaps you run all five lines every time? In that case you use different data each time.

Comment: `summary(bag_mods)` . In real life, I'm always using the same dataset. Here, once I created the dataset, I didn't run the code again.

Comment: To me `summary(bag_mods)` gives the same each time.

Comment: What about things such as `rnorm(1)`? Does `set.seed` work there?